# What is a simple example of a free group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, definition, examples-counterexamples, free-groups

Can someone give me a simple example of a free group with a basis, given the definition below? I don't think I'm understanding the definition clearly.

For example if $F= (\Bbb Z, +)$, $X = \{0\}$, $\phi\colon\{0\} \rightarrow G$ is any function, then there should exist a unique homomorphism $\tilde \phi\colon \Bbb Z \rightarrow G$ such that $\tilde \phi(0) = \phi(0)$.

But if $\phi\colon\{0\} \mapsto \text{non identity element of $G$}$, then there's no way any homomorphism exists because identities of one group are mapped to the other group.

[image]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The simplest example is $(\mathbb{Z},+)$ with the basis $X=\{1\}$. Let $\varphi$ be any function from $X$ into a group $G$ and let $g=\varphi(1)$. Now, define $\tilde{\varphi}(m)=g^m$, for each integer $m$. Then $\tilde\varphi$ is a group homomorphism. Furthermore, it is the *only* group homomorphism from $(\mathbb{Z},+)$ into $G$ such that $\tilde\varphi(1)=\varphi(1)$.

Answer (score 7):

The simplest non-abelian example is $F_2$, with generating set $S=\{a,b\}$. The elements are just reduced words of the form $a^{r_1}b^{s_1}\cdots a^{r_n}b^{s_n}$. In fact, $F_2$ can be shown to be isomorphic to a matrix subgroup of $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$, namely the subgroup generated by 
$$ a =
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 \\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}, 
\ \ \ \ \ b = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
2 & 1
\end{pmatrix},
$$
see the [Ping-Pong Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ping-pong_lemma).

Answer (score 4):

You have a set $X$. The elements of $F_X$ the free group on $X$ are
"reduced words" in $X$; finite sequences of symbols $x$ and $x^{-1}$
for $x\in X$ where no $x$ and $x^{-1}$ are adjacent and including the
empty word, which I'll write as $1$ as it is the identity. So for $X=\{x,y,z\}$ reduced words include $1$, $x$, $y$, $z^{-1}$, $yx$, $xzx^{-1}$, $xxyx^{-1}z^{-1}xzy^{-1}z$ etc. To multiply, concatenate, and cancel any $xx^{-1}$s or $x^{-1}x$s.

If you have $X=\{x\}$ with one element, the reduced words are $1$,
$xx\cdots x$ (with $n$ $x$s) and $x^{-1}x^{-1}\cdots x^{-1}$ (with $n$ $x^{-1}$s). If we write these instead as $x^0$, $x^n$ and $x^{-n}$
we see that $F_X\cong\Bbb Z$.

Rather perversely, in your notation you have chosen $0$ to be the element. This results in reduced words like $0000$ and $0^{-1}0^{-1}0^{-1}$. These can cause confusion...

Answer (score 1):

Whilst it is important to understand the formal definition of free groups, I shall give you a more *geometric* example heralding from algebraic topology, because intuitively it is more of use.

Imagine that you have a flower which has only two petals. Consider also that the meeting point of these two petals is of dimension 0 (namely it is a point). Now, the **free group on *two* generators** describes exactly the difficulty for a small insect to walk on the contour of the petals (no flying's allowed!). This "difficulty" is formally defined in algebraic topology as the **fundamental group** of that surface. Obviously, if you had a flower with k-petals (imagine a bouquet), then the **free group on *k* generators** would express the respective difficulty to walk on all these petals.

Answer (score 0):

The identity in F is the *empty* word.  This alleviates your problem because X consists of *elements* of F (not "0"). X has no identity.   X isn't a group;  it's just a set.